# Scrapy response.urljoin incomplete url

Tags: python, scrapy, urllib

Since [scrapy.http.response.html.HtmlResponse.urljoin](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Response.urljoin) is based on [urllib.parse.urljoin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urljoin) It looks like this behavior is acceptable:

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urljoin
>>> base_url = 'https://url/part1'
>>> extension = 'extension'
>>> urljoin(base_url, extension)
'https://url/extension'
```

What if I want it to be `https://url/part1/extension`?

**and same applies for**

```
>>> urljoin('https://url/part1/part2', extension)
'https://url/part1/extension'
```

I am expecting or need it to be `https://url/part1/part2/extension`

Is there a way to do it without manually concatenating strings?

```
full_url = '/'.join([item.strip('/') for item in [base_url, extension]])
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that your base does not end in a `/`, therefore url join will replace the last part of the url instead of appending to it. Here is an example:

```py
ext = 'two'
base = 'http://example.com/one/four'
url = urljoin(base, ext) # Result = 'http://example.com/one/two'
base = 'http://example.com/one/'
url = urljoin(base, ext) # Result ='http://example.com/one/two'
```

See the [urljoin documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urljoin)

Comment: This implies I need to check which group the response belongs to (ends with `/` vs. doesn't) and manually concatenate `/` if necessary before calling urljoin, which is sort of the same headache I am trying to avoid.

Comment: And it's pretty useless specially, I'm not directly accessing the url using `response.url`, I call `response.urljoin` directly which is exactly where the problems start.